# WSOD on 7.20 after failed attempt to update web form, media, ctools, context modules

Tags: updating, wsod, chaos-tool-suite

Attempted to run security updates for those modules. Update failed. Can't login. WSOD.

(Hosted on Bluehost shared server) Error Message from log:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function page_manager_get_current_page() in ../public_html/sites/all/modules/panels/panels_mini/panels_mini.module on line 146

I've followed various instructions for getting site out of maintenance mode but continue to get WSOD.

Status message Operating in maintenance mode. Go online. (But "go online" doesn't go)

Error message
There is a security update available for your version of Drupal. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.
There are security updates available for one or more of your modules or themes. To ensure the security of your server, you should update immediately! See the available updates page for more information and to install your missing updates.
OK
Web server  Apache
OK
PHP 5.4.26
OK
PHP register globals    Disabled
OK
PHP extensions  Enabled
OK
Database support    Enabled
OK
PHP memory limit    128M
OK
File system Writable (public download method)

Error
Unresolved dependency   context (Missing)
Context layouts requires this module.

Error
Unresolved dependency   page_manager (Missing)
Chaos Tools (CTools) Plugin Example requires this module.

Error
Unresolved dependency   page_manager (Missing)
Custom breadcrumbs for panels requires this module.

Error
Unresolved dependency   context (Missing)
Date Context requires this module.

OK
Unicode library PHP Mbstring Extension

Comment: Well I managed to get the update.php page to load and have a few unresolved dependencies. What is the way to proceed?

Comment: Just install the missing module dependencies via ftp, this should work. You probably have to upgrade to a newer core-version as well...